# How to Convert between Interface derived types?

Tags: c#, derived-types

In the most simplest for here is what I want to do:

```
interface InterfaceA
{
    string var1 { get; set; }
    string var2 { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedA : InterfaceA
{
    public string var1 { get; set; }
    public string var2 { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedB : InterfaceA
{
    public string var1 { get; set; }
    public string var2 { get; set; }
}

public class DoEverything
{
    InterfaceA A = new DerivedA();
    InterfaceA B = new DerivedB();

    A.var1 = "Test1";
    A.var2 = "Test2";

    B = ConvertObject<DerivedB>(A);

    write(B.var1 + ", " + B.var2);

    // This doesn't work, I would like it to though.
    public T ConvertObject<T>(object obj)
    {
        T result = (T)typeof(T).GetConstructor(new Type[] { }).Invoke(new object[] { });

        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (propertyInfo.CanRead)
            {
                try
                {
                    object value = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(result, value, null);
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Right now I have to manually convert each property in my objects and when a new property is added I have to remember to go the conversion methods and add it. I would much prefer that this be done automatically.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could add a constructor to, say, DerivedB, that takes InterfaceA as an argument.

E.g.

```
public class DerivedB : InterfaceA
{
    public string var1 { get; set; }
    public string var2 { get; set; }
    public DerivedB(InterfaceA original)
    {
       var1 = original.var1;
       var2 = original.var2;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as such:

```
public class DoEverything
{
    InterfaceA A = new DerivedA();

    A.var1 = "Test1";
    A.var2 = "Test2";

    InterfaceA B = new DerivedB(A);
    write(B.var1 + ", " + B.var2);
}
```

Comment: That still leaves me with the responsibility of updating all derived classes with a constructor to handle that and then I still have to remember to add to the constructor for every derived class.

Comment: You can create an abstract base class containing a "Create" method and call that (either from DoEverything or from the constructors). In any case you would only need to create constructors on the possible "convert to" classes, not necessarily in all of them.

Comment: This is probably the route I will have to take if someone can't help me with a more efficient method. I does have it's problems though

Comment: It's pretty much the standard OO way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I don't know what you're getting at. Why wouldn't you just declare constructors for DerivedA and DerivedB that take an InterfaceA for initialization? It would be simpler and more flexible, as each derived type would be responsible for initializing itself from the interface type. You could later add more types that implement the interface and they'd be usable by the other classes without any further changes.

Comment: The reason for this is my business layer has a generic dummy class that simply gets and sets each property for the Interface. My real class though is not accessible by the business layer. I am needing to serialize the real class and send it to a webservice for computations. I can't serialize an Interface and my original class is not implemented in my business layer for reasons that frustrate me but that I cannot control. So I have to convert my original class to my dummy class and then serialize. Adding a constructor that takes the Interface type doesn't help because I could just as easily...

Comment: declare the class as DerivedB B = new DerivedB() { blah = A.blah, etc... } which still requires manual translation from A to B

Comment: It's still a simple answer because you are working with a known interface. In your dummy class implement FromA and ToA methods, eaxh of which takes an InterfaceA as a single argument. FromA gets the property values from the arg, ToA does the reverse. You don't need reflection if you know what InterfaceA is.

Comment: Also, while reflection is convenient, there is a definite performance penalty to pay. You may also run into issues with read-only and computed properties that you wouldn't actually want to be copied. And since we don't know how the serialization is being done, there may be some issues there. Yes, it's a pain to update things by hand, but it also gives you the chance to make sure it's done right. And presumably the interface isn't changing that much, is it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [operator overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tk49fh2.aspx) for both derived classes:

Comment: Thanks, again though this requires modifying a method each time I change the Interface to include more properties. I really want to make this a one shot one kill method that I could use for all derived classes of all interfaces. As long as they shared the same ancestor that is. Obviously I can't convert class Cat to class Toaster.

Comment: @user580270: Then you should use reflection but it's rather slow and anyway - a bad idea

Comment: If I were to choose reflection how would I implement that?

Comment: @user580270: Everything after `GetType()` - is the Reflection